# How selenium webdriver is maintaining separate session for each run?

Tags: java, session, selenium-webdriver, session-cookies

For example in gmail login, when we consider a login test, when doing it manually for the first time we'll get the login page, from next time onwards we'll be directly getting into the inbox page.

If you try to do the same thing in webdriver(Run login test twice), in all these attempts we'll get the login page as we didn't login from this machine earlier. What is happening in behind the scenes in maintaining the session with respect to cookies or session ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the description & code snippet from selenium docs to add or remove cookies:

> Before we leave these next steps, you may be interested in
>   understanding how to use cookies. First of all, you need to be on the
>   domain that the cookie will be valid for. If you are trying to preset
>   cookies before you start interacting with a site and your homepage is
>   large / takes a while to load an alternative is to find a smaller page
>   on the site, typically the 404 page is small
>   (http://example.com/some404page)

```
// Go to the correct domain
driver.get("http://www.example.com");

// Now set the cookie. This one's valid for the entire domain
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("key", "value");
driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);

// And now output all the available cookies for the current URL
Set<Cookie> allCookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
for (Cookie loadedCookie : allCookies) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%s -> %s", loadedCookie.getName(), loadedCookie.getValue()));
}

// You can delete cookies in 3 ways
// By name
driver.manage().deleteCookieNamed("CookieName");
// By Cookie
driver.manage().deleteCookie(loadedCookie);
// Or all of them
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, here I would like to understand, how selenium is performing all these activities without managing cookies explicitly ? For example, every time when we login to gmail, we are getting a login page, instead of directly login to account. How it's managing(deleting) previously generated session ?

Comment: You can configure selenium to whether or not use cookies. Here is the snippet for it: FirefoxProfile profile=new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("network.cookie.cookieBehavior",2); Check this link for different values for network.cookie.cookieBehavior: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.cookie.cookieBehavior